# Django ORM can not count number of dates between two dates / naive datetime problem

Tags: django, date, datetime, django-models, django-orm

I have a model which we register enter and exit dates. I want to count the number of days in given period of time.

Here is the model:

```
class EnterExit(models.Model):
    people= models.ForeignKey(People, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Enter= models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Enter Hour',auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False)
    Exit= models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Exit Hour',auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False)

class Calculation(models.Model):
    people= models.ForeignKey(People, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Personel')
    PeriodStart = models.DateField(verbose_name='Start of Period', auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    PeriodEnd = models.DateField(verbose_name='End of Period', auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
        

    def Count(self):
         NumberOfDays = EnterExit.objects.filter(personel_id = self.personel.PersonelABNu)\
                     .filter(Enter__gte = self.PeriodStart)\
                     .filter(Enter__lte = self.PeriodEnd).count()
         return NumberOfDays
```

Here is the problem: I want to find how many times does a person enters between this time range. I have 30 enters and exits for a person however, my query finds 29. It is always one less and I could not find the reason.

Do you have any idea and suggestions?

Thanks !

**UPDATE:**

I have noticed that there is an error which leads to miscount.

RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField EnterExit.Exit received a naive datetime (2022-07-01 00:00:00) whi
le time zone support is active. warnings.warn("DateTimeField %s.%s received a naive datetime "

How can I overcome this problem? Thank you!

Comment: There is a `range` filter in Django which can fit here. See if this shows the right count for you. Ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#range

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. Result is same. I noticed that there is a naive datetime problem however, do not know how to solve it.